# How to adjust the time length for getting into a deep sleep

Tags: android

I am not sure if I had understood it correctly.. but it seems that android has a sleep mode 
where everything is paused except the background services and a deep sleep mode that turns off
everything even the CPU.

So I wonder if there is there a way to control the time before getting into a deep sleep mode. Couldn't find any official documentation about the sleep modes.. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is this for an app or something else?

Comment: @MorrisonChang app, system setting.. what ever that does that will be good. Since I want to test my app for resuming from deep sleep..just want to make the sleep faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but it seems that android has a sleep mode where everything is paused except the background services and a deep sleep mode that turns off everything even the CPU.

AFAIK, there is only one sleep mode, corresponding to what you describe as "deep sleep". Certainly, from an SDK developer standpoint, either the device is awake, asleep, or off.

> So I wonder if there is there a way to control the time before getting into a deep sleep mode.

Not really. You control how long the screen is on via the Settings app. How long before the device falls asleep after that will range from milliseconds to centuries depending upon what is going on with the device (e.g., is anything holding a `WakeLock`).

Comment: Hey man, I found a method goToSleep(long time) in the PowerManager class.. but it crashes if I use it and throws:java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10081 nor current process has android.permission.DEVICE_POWER. I added it in the Manifest and still does that..not sure why

Comment: @Han: Standard SDK applications are not allowed to hold that permission.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this! I tried to look for a alternative way for rooted device but couldn't find anything..I think I will just test the sleep by leaving the device over night